# Constraints on Type Parameter Clarification please

Tags: c#

Could someone please clarify what the code means:

```
public abstract class BaseJobProcessor<T> : JobProcessor where T : BaseQueueMessage  {}
```

Thank you v. much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that any type that fills the position of `T` must be either `BaseQueueMessage` itself, or a class derived from it.

So you can say

```
public class MyQueueMessage : BaseQueueMessage { ... }

public class MyJobProcessor<T> : BaseJobProcessor<T> where T : BaseQueueMessage { ... }

MyJobProcessor<MyQueueMessage> jobProcessor = ...
```

But you can't say

```
MyJobProcessor<string> jobProcessor =
```

Because `string` is not derived from `BaseQueueMessage`

Comment: Thanks all, all valid answer @siride's example helped me to understnad better

Comment: @flybyte: but do take note of BrokenGlass's second paragraph, which explains another reason why constraints are useful.

Answer (score 3):

```
public abstract class BaseJobProcessor<T> : JobProcessor where T :  BaseQueueMessage  {}
```

It's a definition of an abstract generic class that has one type parameter `T` which is of type `BaseQueueMessage` . It will cause a compile time error to try to create any instance of a generic class derived from `BaseJobProcessor` and pass it a type parameter of a type that is not derived from `BaseQueueMessage`.

This is usually done so you can make some assumptions for `T` within the code of the BaseJobProcessor class, in this example it would allow to use all public methods and properties defined on `BaseQueueMessage` on all instances of type `T` that are created/accessed within `BaseJobProcessor<T>.` (If you didn't have the constraint you would only be able to use `object` method/properties on any instance of type `T`)